# Code First nullable Foreign Key not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I made a .Net MVC project. First I have created a ClassLibrary with all models and Db Contexts and i used this library in working with database. Now i want to use this class library in another project from another solution. I made a reference to class library but this new project does not recognize nullable Foreign keys (such as "strings" or nullable "Int"). Error ocuurs on runtime.

Class example

```
[Table("PORT_CALLS")]
public class PORT_CALLS
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 SID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SHIP_CALLS")]
    public Int64 SHIP_CALL_SID { get; set; }

    public virtual SHIP_CALLS SHIP_CALLS{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MNG_OPERATORS")]
    public Int64 ? OPERATOR_SID { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual MNG_OPERATORS MNG_OPERATORS { get; set; }

    public Decimal ? FORE_DRAUGHT { get; set; }

    public Decimal ? MID_SHIP_DRAUGHT { get; set; }

    public Decimal ? AFT_DRAUGHT { get; set; }

    public Decimal ? AIR_DRAUGHT { get; set; }

    public Int16 ? IS_TANKER { get; set; }
}
```

Error: Entity Type has no key defined Define the key for this EntityType (this error occurs for all nullable foreign keys)

Comment: Does the new project you're referencing from target the same version of framework as the shared project?

Comment: You have "no key defined" for some entities, i.e. not *primary* key. The error should also give you the names of the faulty entities.

Comment: The model is well formated because it is used successfully by other applications.  I observed that the model is incompatible only with MVC API projects (when i use this library in WindowsForm applications or console app,it works). I use allways the same version of framework in all projects (4.5).

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to the `SHIP_CALLS` property with the name of the property that offers the foreign key:

```
[ForeignKey("SHIP_CALL_SID")]
public virtual SHIP_CALLS SHIP_CALLS{ get; set; }
```